# Change the Query of the cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

Dears 
I am working with PL-SQL
and I need to define a cursor and then change the query
of this cursor...
How I can change the Query of the cursor

thx

Comment: I agree with @Codo. Please clarify your question, otherwise we can only guess what you really are asking.

Comment: First off, you CAN'T do EXACTLY what you're asking. A cursor is derived from a query... think of cursor as CURrent Set Of Records. It's the recordset that a query produces. Once a query is run to create the Cursor, you can' just change the query.

Comment: Smell like homework without some sort of context. What is the business issue you need to address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use an Oracle REF CURSOR.

[This](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Oracle/Working-with-REF-CURSOR-in-PL-SQL/) is a decent tutorial about REF CURSORs, but I'm sure google can provide you with more examples.